# Does any version of King's Bounty contain city building?

Tags: kings-bounty-the-legend, kings-bounty-dark-side, kings-bounty-crossworlds

Right now, there are seven King's Bounty games and countless DLC for them, I'm playing Legends right now.

However, until now I can only buy units at preset locations and have no way to build my home base at all. It gets really repetitive after a while to just walk and hexgridfight all the time without the "advanced" strategies that come with a build tree and resource management.

So, does any of the games and/or DLC offer town building like in Heroes of Might and Magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they do not.

The original King's Bounty game came out in 1990 and inspired the combat system of the Heroes of Might & Magic series. HoMM is what you should play if you want combat similar to KB, but with city building. All the games in the modern KB franchise are fairly similar; none of them dramatically change up *The Legend*'s formula.

You mentioned "seven games and countless DLC for them." Really, there aren't that many. There are effectively four games in the main KB franchise right now.

- King's Bounty: The Legend
- <s>King's Bounty: Armored Princess</s>
- King's Bounty: Crossworlds (An stand-alone expansion which contains the entirety of Armored Princess)
- King's Bounty: Warriors of the North (has a single DLC)
- King's Bounty: Dark Side (has a single DLC)

There is also a free-to-play spin-off called *King's Bounty: Legions* which was originally exclusive to Facebook and which has a lot of DLC. Unlike the other games, this one has timers and micro-transactions. It appears to reuse a lot of content from the main games and is mostly notable for it's inclusion of player vs player combat.